# Bind incoming packets to 1 interface and outgoing packets to 2nd interface?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, network-adapter

I am have a Linux machine with 2 network interface cards, I need to use one for incoming packets, other for outgoing packets.

[image: Current Scenario]

Comment: Using a different address when sending would break all upper-layer protocols, except maybe SCTP.

Comment: @BatchyX Is this possible anyhow to use one interface for incoming packets and other for outgoing ..I am a newbie so could you please hint some factors

Comment: If you use only one IP address, this is almost trivial to do.

Comment: But... if your if2 sends out packets, the server will reply to ip2. How do you want to tell the server to reply to ip1 instead?

Comment: @BatchyX can changing routing table could be the solution .please take a look at it .and reply to me .today is the last day for me to do this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531835/bind-outgoing-traffic-to-eth0-instead-of-eth01

Comment: @BatchyX is this possible to use same IP address for two different interfaces .IF using same IP address will help me out >please refer me a soluion

Comment: @Konerak yes this is exactly what I am thinking .but i am asked to give a solution for using one IP for incoming  and other for outgoing packets .For binding a interface for outgoing connections is possible i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531835/bind-outgoing-traffic-to-eth0-instead-of-eth01

Comment: @BatchyX Can this be done .
http://i.stack.imgur.com/n5uYb.png

Comment: @Konerak Can this be done http://i.stack.imgur.com/n5uYb.png

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: @BatchyX Yes ,but apparently it looks like as solution to my problem (Although it is not.)Could you please help if this could be done and  i have a switch in between my Linux machine and network .May be something could be done at switch end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept to use a single IP/prefix on your machine (let's name it X.X.X.X/Y, with gateway G.G.G.G), then it can be trivially be done.

- Add your address to `eth0`, but with a full prefix subnet.

  e.g. `ip addr add X.X.X.X/32 dev eth0`
- Do not set an address on eth1. If there is one, clear it with `ip -4 addr flush dev eth1`
- Add the subnet and gateway routes via `eth1`

  `ip route add X.X.X.X/Y dev eth1`
  `ip route add default via G.G.G.G dev eth1`
- If on Ubuntu, or on other Linux distributions that enables Reverse Path Filtering by default, disable it, as they assume and enforce symmetric routing.

  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 0`
  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0`
- If both your network interfaces are connected to a switch, then you will need to not answer ARP on eth1. Since we added the IP address to `eth0`, we can just set `arp_ignore` on `eth1` to 1 (only answer ARP for `eth1` addresses) or 8 (don't answer anything).

  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.arp_ignore = 8`

Once this configuration is done, there will be only one traffic that will flow in the reverse order: If the kernel receives an ARP request for X.X.X.X from `eth0`, then it will reply using `eth0`.